# Wildcard and Naked CNAME records in Azure DNS

Tags: powershell, azure, dns

I'm migrating all my DNS services to Azure DNS. Using Powershell I've managed to successfully create the CNAME record to get www.something.com to resolve to an Azure website-

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "www" -RecordType "CNAME" -ZoneName "something.com" -ResourceGroupName "DNSRecords" -Ttl 60 -Overwrite -Force
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Cname "MySomethingAzureWebsite.azurewebsites.net"
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs -Overwrite
```

But how to I create CNAME records for wildcard and naked addresses like

*.something.com or something.com

I'm assuming it's something (no pun intended) to do with

**New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "www"**

But through all the documentation and Internet examples I can't seem to find the right verbiage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is an issue with the [rules of DNS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034), which forbid a CNAME record where another record exists. The naked address (or Apex) example.com already has two records (the SOA and NS) so a CNAME is not allowed.

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
> present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
> cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
> used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

In order to create an Apex record, i.e. example.com you need to use an A record, which means it needs to point to the IP of your Azure website. Once you have that you can then create a CNAME from www to example.com. (this is the supported method - your IP Address for Azure websites is static)

the command you are looking for, would be something like

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "@" -RecordType A `
       -ZoneName example.com -ResourceGroupName $RG `
       -Ttl $ttl -Force -Overwrite
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Ipv4Address $IPAddress
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs -Overwrite
```

then

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "www" -RecordType "CNAME" `
      -ZoneName "something.com" -ResourceGroupName "DNSRecords" `
      -Ttl 60 -Overwrite -Force
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Cname "example.com"
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs -Overwrite
```

This will create your zone apex record and point the www cname to it making example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) point to the same place.

For a Wildcard you replace the Apex "@" with an asterix "*" so something like

```
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "*" -RecordType A `
       -ZoneName example.com -ResourceGroupName $RG `
       -Ttl $ttl -Force -Overwrite
#You know the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer stated, you can't create a CNAME at the zone apex (name = "@").  This is because of the RFC constraints, and the correct approach is to use other record types e.g. A records at the zone apex instead, as the previous respondent explained.

However, you can create a wildcard CNAME at the zone apex.  Since wildcards do not match against empty strings in DNS, they do not fall foul of the RFC constraints.  For example, in PowerShell:

```
$z = New-AzureRmDnsZone -Name myzone.com -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup
$rs = New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -Name "*" -Zone $z -Ttl 3600 -RecordType CNAME
Add-AzureRmDnsRecordConfig -RecordSet $rs -Cname cnametarget.com
Set-AzureRmDnsRecordSet -RecordSet $rs
```

This will resolve for queries to e.g. foo.myzone.com but not for myzone.com.

[Wikipedia has a good page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) to learn more about wildcard DNS.

Comment: Is the real problem that some services like DNSimple have 'invented' their own custom records like Alias and URL (https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/)  that make managing zone file easier but do a lot of work under the covers to make all that RFC compliant. Then people like me move from their services to ones that don;t have those features and we're stumped how to get things working?

Comment: That's one way to put it.  Part of the challenge is that features such as 'alias' records are non-standard and can therefore have unexpected effects.  For example, from a DNS standards perspective, an 'alias' record needs to resolve like an A record, even though it's configured like a CNAME record.  Behind the scenes, the DNS provider needs to resolve the alias target into an A record.  Under some circumstances this can cause unexpected side-effects, e.g. if the DNS record behind that alias target changes, or is part of a traffic-management system that depends on the source query IP address.