# Azure DNS CNAME records

Tags: azure, authentication, networking, auth0

I am trying to configure Auth0 custom domains with my azure web application. It is asking for a CNAME Record to be set.

[image: auth0 provided record]

I set this up in azure with a provided dns name, and set up the values as such:

[image: azure provided record]

but the verify button still does not work. i heard you may need to wait a few days for it to settle, but i waited all weekend with no luck. i saw in this post i may want to remove the  NS and SOA types?

[Wildcard and Naked CNAME records in Azure DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585964/wildcard-and-naked-cname-records-in-azure-dns)

how can i verify this domain

Comment: Could you write the DNS records you have specified in the question (with the actual domain name replace with like company.com)? We cannot verify that you have configured it correctly at the moment.

Comment: the ns and soa came prebuilt when i started this in azure. ns is just nameserver 1-4,
soa is Email: azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com
Host: (nameserver1)//modified
Refresh: 3600
Retry: 300
Expire: 2419200
Minimum TTL: 300
Serial number: 1  
Refresh: 3600

CNAME is exactly what was given by Auth0

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: I think your answer is about as correct as it can be. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not use the domain `*.cloudapp.azure.com` as the **custom domain** for your Auth0 as it is owned by Azure. You need to purchase a domain from the domain provider like [Godaddy](https://domains.google/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2bTiou6g6AIVGAkrCh2sHwoxEAAYAyAAEgK4GvD_BwE) to configure your **custom domain**. Then you could validate that domain ownership.

You can't use Azure DNS to buy a domain name. Azure DNS is a hosting service for DNS domains that provides name resolution by using Microsoft Azure infrastructure. It's not necessary. You can selectly [host your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns).

For more references:

https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains/auth0-managed-certificates#provide-your-domain-name-to-auth0